# Grouping Entries in Infinite Scroll

Tags: playa

So I am building out a homepage that is going to have a infinite scroll of entries. Though there are entries that are apart of a parent entry, and I will be displaying the parent entries Title. And each child entry is a part of a week. And the week is a category set on each child entry, and the category will be visible. Below is an example.

Parent Entry Title
Week 1 - Entry 1 Entry 2 Entry 3 Entry 4 Entry 5
Week 2 - Entry 1 Entry 2 Entry 3 Entry 4 Entry 5
Parent Entry Title
Week 1 - Entry 1 Entry 2 Entry 3 Entry 4 Entry 5
Week 2 - Entry 1 Entry 2 Entry 3 Entry 4 Entry 5

I can't figure out the syntax for this so it can be displayed in an infinite scroll, but where it displays all entries while grouped. I have achieved it but it loops out the same thing 5 times.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="foo" site="mainsite"}
    {exp:playa:parents site="mainsite"}
        {if title}
            {title}
        {/if}
        {exp:playa:children site="mainsite" field="foo_entries"}
            {title}
        {/exp:playa:children}
    {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to achieve this I put my 5 entries in a parent entry, so I could out put the title and all the entries. And used jQuery to get the week number.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="foo" site="bar"}
    {title}
    {exp:playa:children}
        <li class="week_7">{title}</li>
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.week_7').wrapAll('<ul class="foobar"/>');
        $('.week_6').wrapAll('<ul class="foobar"/>');
        $('.week_5').wrapAll('<ul class="foobar"/>');
        $('.week_4').wrapAll('<ul class="foobar"/>');
        $('.week_3').wrapAll('<ul class="foobar"/>');
        $('.week_2').wrapAll('<ul class="foobar"/>');
        $('.week_1').wrapAll('<ul class="foobar"/>');
        $('.foobar').each(function () {
            var weeknum = $(this).children('li:first').prop('class');
            var weeknum = weeknum.match(/\d+/);
            $(this).prepend('<li class="week week_'+weeknum+'"><img src="/images/theme/week'+weeknum+'.png" alt=""/></li>');
        });
    });
```